# using shell script to format text file content

Tags: regex, linux, shell

Thing is I want to format my text file content using shell script . Content is like :

```
http://copyright.gov.in Inlinks:
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/ anchor: Copyright
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/hi/home anchor: कॉपीराइट
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/?fontsize=normal anchor: Copyright
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/?contrast=high anchor: Copyright
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/?fontsize=large anchor: Copyright
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/sitemap anchor: Copyright
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/?fontsize=small anchor: Copyright
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/hi anchor: कॉपीराइट
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/?contrast=normal anchor: Copyright
```

I want formatted output as:

```
http://copyright.gov.in -> http://mhrd.gov.in/
http://copyright.gov.in -> http://mhrd.gov.in/hi/home 
http://copyright.gov.in -> http://mhrd.gov.in/?fontsize=normal
```

and so on

Comment: `Please help me with this .Please` -- only if you demonstrate that you attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: You should use the right tool for the right job and i don't think that text processing is part of any shell's core business. `perl`, `awk`, etc. are way better at such tasks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat foo.input
http://copyright.gov.in Inlinks:
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/ anchor: foo
 fromUrl: http://mhrd.gov.in/hi anchor: bar
http://foo.acme.gov Inlinks:
 fromUrl: http://foo.acme.gov/ anchor: foo
 fromUrl: http://foo.acme.gov/about anchor: bar
```

```
$ awk '/^http/ { host=$1; next } NF { printf "%s -> %s\n", host, $2 }' foo.input
http://copyright.gov.in -> http://mhrd.gov.in/
http://copyright.gov.in -> http://mhrd.gov.in/hi
http://foo.acme.gov -> http://foo.acme.gov/
http://foo.acme.gov -> http://foo.acme.gov/about
```